# Error install phonegap-plugin-push cordova-ios version >= 5

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an application on ionic 3 and after upgrading cordova-ios to 5.0 I can no longer install the phonegap-plugin-push plugin.

See the error I get:

```
> cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for ios
"framework" tag with type "podspec" is deprecated and will be removed. Please use the "podspec" tag.
Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': undefined
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/...../node_modules/.bin in PATH, mode 040777\n' +
  "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': \u001b[31m[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.\u001b[39m (CLAide::Help)\n" +
  '\n' +
  '\u001b[4mUsage:\u001b[24m\n' +
  '\n' +
  '    $ \u001b[32mpod\u001b[39m \u001b[32mCOMMAND\u001b[39m\n' +
  '\n' +
  '      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.\n' +
  '\n' +
  '\u001b[4mCommands:\u001b[24m\n' +
  '\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ cache\u001b[39m      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ env\u001b[39m        Display pod environment\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ init\u001b[39m       Generate a Podfile for the current directory\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ install\u001b[39m    Install project dependencies according to versions from a\n' +
  '                 Podfile.lock\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ ipc\u001b[39m        Inter-process communication\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ lib\u001b[39m        Develop pods\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ list\u001b[39m       List pods\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ outdated\u001b[39m   Show outdated project dependencies\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ repo\u001b[39m       Manage spec-repositories\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ setup\u001b[39m      Setup the CocoaPods environment\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ spec\u001b[39m       Manage pod specs\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ update\u001b[39m     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock\n' +
  '\n' +
  '\u001b[4mOptions:\u001b[24m\n' +
  '\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--silent\u001b[39m     Show nothing\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--version\u001b[39m    Show the version of the tool\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--verbose\u001b[39m    Show more debugging information\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--no-ansi\u001b[39m    Show output without ANSI codes\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--help\u001b[39m       Show help banner of specified command\n' +
  "\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'\n" +
  "\tfrom /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'\n"
    at /Users/.../node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:29:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Already tried to update the pod.
my pod version is 1.8.4

I've done pod update, CocoaPods update and nothing solves.

Can anyone give me a hint?

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.13 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.3.0
```

Comment: Try removing the platforms and adding them again, then try installing the plugin.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Yes, I already did that. It did not solve.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the decision was made to downgrade to cordova-ios version 4.5.5 to maintain compatibility with the plugins.